# How do I take MySQL data i have pulled with PHP and use it in another page without creating millions of pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So i have a exercise site in the making and at the moment there are hundreds of exercises displayed. I dont have a problem pulling the data from the MySQL database. My issue is being able to view each exercise on a separate page. At the moment all of the exercises are pulled in using this function:

```
//Category 1 is biceps 
$cat = 1;
//$category is used for the case statement, to allow the form to submit and refresh         to the case statement that it is on, for each instance of the function. 
$category = 'biceps';
show_exercise($cat, $category);
```

here is the function itself:

```
//Show exercises based on exercise category 
function show_exercise($cat, $category)
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE cat_id='$cat' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output[] = '<div class="item"> 
        <h2>'. $row['name'] .'</h2> 
        <img src="'. $row['image'] .'" alt="'. $row['name'] .'" /> 
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="add" value="add" /> 
        <a href="index.php?p=view"><input class="button" type="submit" name="view" value="view"/></a> 
        </div>';
    }
    echo join('', $output);
}
```

now this just pulls all of my different exercises onto one page as an array. I want to be able to select and view each individual exercise but i don't know how. One way would be to create a page for every exercise, but i have hundreds. The buttons in the code above aren't being used, but the idea is that when someone clicks the 'view' button, they are taken to a separate page of the exercise where they can read more detail. All of the data that has been used in the code above from the database can be used on the individual exercise pages.

My pages are managed with a switch statement, i thought i'd mention this as it might change the answer. Here is the switch statement i'm using:

```
// Validate what page to show: 

if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
    $p = $_GET['p'];
}
elseif(isset($_POST['p']))
{
// Forms 
    $p = $_POST['p'];
}
else 
{
    $p = NULL;
}
// Determine what page to display: 

switch ($p)
{
    case  'contact' : 
        $page = 'contact.php';
        $page_title = 'Contact Us';
    break;

    case  'exercises' : 
        $page = 'exercises.php';
        $page_title = 'Exercises';
    break;

    case  'routines' : 
        $page = 'routines.php';
        $page_title = 'Your Routines';
    break;

    case  'arms' : 
        $page = 'arms.php';
        $page_title = 'arms routine';
    break;
}
```

this statement goes on with more pages. I dont know if im making this sound harder than what it is. I'll be ready to comment if there are any questions.

Comment: Dear god man - use a framework!

Frameworks will manage a lot of those issue for you, while still giving you the flexibility to do what you need. Check out [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter).

Comment: I'm learning codeigniter. Our tutor wont allow us to use a framework :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to select and view each individual exercise but i don't know how. One way would be to create a page for every exercise, but i have hundreds.

What do you mean by "page"?

Anyway, you actually don't need more than one PHP script because it can pass query string parameters to itself. But it is usually easier to maintain if you distribute it over several pages. It looks like you're already doing this. Good.

For example you can add a parameter called "itemid" that is only used when you access the "view" page.

If the view-page is implemented in another script (I'll call this "page script") that is included from your mother-script, I recommend that all your "page scripts" implement the same function called i.e. `generate_page($query_string)` that is called with the query-string from the mother-script. If you used OOP, each page could be a class implementing the same interface. But I'm trying to suggest something similar to what you're already doing.

So something like this for your mother-page:

```
<?php
$pagename = $_GET["page"];
$allowed_pages = ["view", "contact"];
if (!in_array($pagename,$allowed_pages)) exit("Invalid page!");
require($page . ".php");
generate_page($_GET);
?>
```

view.php

```
<?php
function generate_page($arguments) {
   if (!isset($arguments["item"])) exit("Item needs to be specified!");
   // Do SQL query and view THIS item. (remember to guard against SQL injection!)
   // you can do this by using a different WHERE clause
}
?>
```

Now view can show what it wants. The other pages don't have to use the `$arguments` parameter if they don't want to.

You could change your link to something like `<a href="index.php?p=view&item={$row['itemid']}">`.

Comment: by pages i mean manually creating a hundred different exercise pages instead of using php. I'm an absolute beginner at PHP. I dont know what your code is doing. If you imagine play.com when you search categories of DVD, and when you click on a DVD it has its own page, thats what i want but for exercises. I have pulled all the data i need. And for each row i have pulled i want to have a view button that when pressed views that specific exercise. do you understand?

Comment: yeah I think I understand. If each exercise has an ID, you can pass that as query-string parameter (which will end up in `$_GET`). Which part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: right, so my page switch statement is in index.php. My functions are in functions.php and the code you said to put in view.php is in there. What is generate_page function?
i dont know how to write the SQL query to view the item.

Comment: i've tried to manipulate the code to my work like this: 
//view page argument
$pagename = $_GET["e_id"];
$allowed_pages = ["view"];
if (!in_array($pagename)) exit("Invalid page!");
require($page . ".php");
generate_page($_GET); 

This is in functions.php

Comment: What is allowed pages, i dont know what any of this code does.

Comment: And $_GET('page') <---- is 'page' e_id? do i need to change that?

Comment: `$allowed_pages` is simply an array of pages that are allowed to be visited, so that you don't need to assign `$page` in every switch branch. Try running the code in your head to see how it works. `$page` will always just be `$p` with ".php" at the end. Checking if it is allowed or not and then always appending if it is allowed, makes the code simpler.